# With more explanatory variables than observations in LR, how does SPSS exclude variables

Tags: regression, linear-regression, spss

I'm using SPSS to do several linear regressions and applying different filters each time in order to compare different groups. For a number of filters, I am fitting regressions with only 13 observations, but 15 or 24 explanatory variables. In those cases, SPSS will give me a model with 12 betas and will exclude the remaining variables (this I understand mostly I think).

Can anyone tell me how SPSS selects the variables to be excluded and what that tells me about those variables' effect on the dependent (i.e. what the betas are then)? I originally thought I should treat those variables as having zero betas, but am not sure anymore.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Please, no comments telling me only that it's stupid to fit regression on 13 observations. If you have some useful insight that requires you to first point out that regression with 13 observations is less than ideal, I'm happy to hear you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very unlikely to get useful results with so many variables and so few observations when the model can be fit at all.  Look at the coefficient standard errors.  You might be better off using a technique like partial least squares (PLS), which can accommodate more variables than cases.  PLS in Statistics is available via as an extension command (Analyze > Regression > Partial Least Squares), however, it requires the installation of some extra libraries beyond the Python Essentials that are normally installed with Statistics.  See the installation instructions with it if you want to pursue this.

As for which variables would be left out using regression, the choice is completely arbitrary, since, barring perfect collinearity, any N variables (including the constant term) will give a perfect fit if there are N cases.

Comment: Thank you JKP. I agree completely, but am unfortunately forced to align my work with what has been done for over 7 years at my company. I thank you also for the suggestion of PLS, I will definitely look into it as best I can. Finally, thank you for the last paragraph, it is exactly what I was looking for. Is the reason for this perfect fit very complicated to understand or do you know of any sources that might explain it in a few pages?

Comment: Well, it follows from basic linear algebra and the normal equations for regression, but maybe an empirical demonstration would be more convincing to your audience.  Generate 3 random variables but only two cases.  Then regress any one on the others.  You will see a perfect fit with only one variable and a constant term used even though the variables have nothing to do with each other.  Once the residuals are zero,  no additional explanatory variables can improve the fit.